# Why does my code crash when I try to use input file with more than 100 edges?

Tags: c, crash, dijkstra, infinity

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define GRAPHSIZE 2048
#define INFINITY GRAPHSIZE*GRAPHSIZE
#define MAX(a, b) ((a > b) ? (a) : (b))

int e; /* The number of nonzero edges in the graph */
int n; /* The number of nodes in the graph */
long dist[GRAPHSIZE][GRAPHSIZE]; 
long d[GRAPHSIZE]; 
int prev[GRAPHSIZE]; 

void printPath(int dest) {
    if (prev[dest] != -1)
        printPath(prev[dest]);
    printf("%d ", dest);
}

void dijkstra(int s) {
    int i, k, mini;
    int visited[GRAPHSIZE];

    for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        d[i] = INFINITY;
        prev[i] = -1; /* no path has yet been found to i */
        visited[i] = 0; /* the i-th element has not yet been visited */
    }

    d[s] = 0;

    for (k = 1; k <= n; ++k) {
        mini = -1;
        for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
            if (!visited[i] && ((mini == -1) || (d[i] < d[mini])))
                mini = i;

        visited[mini] = 1;

        for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
            if (dist[mini][i])
                if (d[mini] + dist[mini][i] < d[i]) {
                    d[i] = d[mini] + dist[mini][i];
                    prev[i] = mini;
                }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i, j;
    int u, v, w;

    FILE *fin = fopen("/Users/kostistougianni/Downloads/networks/net100.txt", "r");
    fscanf(fin, "%d", &e);
    for (i = 0; i < e; ++i)
        for (j = 0; j < e; ++j)
            dist[i][j] = 0;
    n = -1;
    for (i = 0; i < e; ++i) {
        fscanf(fin, "%d%d%d", &u, &v, &w);
        dist[u][v] = w;
        n = MAX(u, MAX(v, n));
    }
    fclose(fin);

    dijkstra(1);

    printf("\n");
    for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        printf("Path to %d: ", i);
        printPath(i);
        printf("\n");
    }

    dijkstra(1);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Path from 1 to 100:");
    printPath(100);

    return 0;
}
```

My text looks like: `1 5 10` which `1 = u, 5 = v, 10 = w`

The code works just fine while I use an inout file with 10-50 edges. After that, when I give an input file with more than 100 edges it gives out a crash without any errors.

Comment: `GRAPHSIZE` might be less than `n`, which will explode at `d[i] = INFINITY` what about it?

Comment: Run your program in a debugger, the debugger will stop at the location of the crash and let you examine and walk up the function call stack, and also let you examine values of variables as each level of the call stack. This should help you locate where the crash happens in your code. If you can't figure it out, then at least please edit your question to show where the crash happens as well as the values of all involved variables.

Comment: I changed graphsize to 100 as my nodes are 100 and now it doesn't seems to crash. But the result is strange because it seems not find any shortcut from node1 - node100

Comment: might stack overflow by recursive call ?